# Select element protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Im having big problems trying to write my end2end testing.

This is my scenario: I want to count the number of options for a given element.

What I **DONT** want to do is to use id's, so Im trying to select it without polluting the html.

Lets see the html:

```
<form class="catalogue-sidebar">
  ...
  <ki-multi-select-option>
    <select>
      ...
      <option></option>
      ...
    </select>
  </ki-multi-select-option><!-- ki-multi-select-option -->
  ...
</form><!-- .catalogue-sidebar -->
```

I have a few ki-multi-select-option directives here.  I need to count lets say, the number of options on the second one.

How can I select it ?

Using id's will be something like this (this works):

```
var colorsOptions = browser.findElements( by.css( '#filter-colors select > option' ) );
colorsOptions.then( function( elements ) {
  // There is an empty option as default, thats why "greater than 1"
  expect( elements.length ).toBeGreaterThan( 1 );
});
```

But as I said, I want to avoid including ids just for testing.

I have tried lot of different combinations but without success.

Using jQuery I could do something like this:

```
$( ".catalogue-sidebar ki-multi-select-option:eq(1)" ).find( 'select > option' )
```

Anybody can help me here ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can directly use "jQuery styled" selector by using $('css-selector') in protractor. See http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=build$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just CSS:

```
var options = element.all(by.css('.catalogue-sidebar ki-multi-select-option:nth-child(1) select option'));
```

Chaining with [get](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) and [all](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.all):

```
var kiWrapper = element.all(by.css('.catalogue-sidebar ki-multi-select-option')).get(1);
var options = kiWrapper.all(by.css('select option'));
```

Now with the [count](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) function there is no need of a `then` since `expect` handles webdriver promises:

```
expect(options.count()).toBeGreaterThan(1);
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I needed, though, the first options (without chaining) isnt working... But the second way did the trick